# Create a table/csv from text string

Tags: python, text, processing

Reposting it as this was incorrectly marked as duplicated. This post was [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)  but does not answer my issue

I am new to Python, I have a text string that looks like this. I need help in converting it to a table. I tried doing it by creating dictionaries, however, the number of columns in each row are not always the same, this is creating an issue. Also, there are columns like "stock" in the text, that I do not need in the final output

After removing empty lines and other info. the text file looks like this.

```
XYZ
XYZ
ABC
ABC
MNP
MNP
Fruit
Apple
price
30
Number
10
Fruit
kiwi
stock
10
Number
20
Fruit
grape
price
12
```

This is my desired output in a table format, the second row should have empty value left for price third row should have an empty value for Number.

```
Fruit    price    Number    
Apple    30       10    
kiwi              20    
grape    12
```

Comment: You could create placeholder empty value (e.g. `None`) for the entry that has a field undefined, then the solutions provided by the linked thread can be applied.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, your question is not clear. Is the apparent format of the text file guaranteed (some starting rows, then lines grouped in pairs, each first line is one of `Fruit`, `price`, or `Number`, the second line is the value, etc.)? Is the "output" to be a csv file or a printout with lined-up columns or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to create such table:

```
import pandas as pd

text = '''XYZ
XYZ
ABC
ABC
MNP
MNP
Fruit
Apple
price
30
Number
10
Fruit
kiwi
Number
20
Fruit
grape
price
12'''

data = {'Fruit': [], 'price': [], 'Number': []}
lines = text.split()
for i in range(len(lines)):
    if i+5 < len(lines) and lines[i] == 'Fruit' and lines[i+2] == 'price' and lines[i+4] == 'Number':
        data['Fruit'].append(lines[i+1])
        data['price'].append(lines[i+3])
        data['Number'].append(lines[i+5])
    elif i+3 < len(lines) and lines[i] == 'Fruit' and lines[i+2] == 'Number':
        data['Fruit'].append(lines[i+1])
        data['price'].append('')
        data['Number'].append(lines[i+3])
    elif i+3 < len(lines) and lines[i] == 'Fruit' and lines[i+2] == 'price':
        data['Fruit'].append(lines[i+1])
        data['price'].append(lines[i+3])
        data['Number'].append('')

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Fruit price Number
0  Apple    30     10
1   kiwi           20
2  grape    12
```

Also you can save result to CSV:

```
df.to_csv('result.csv')
```

Comment: In first `if` I parse first 5 lines of text, that's why `i+5`

Comment: Got it Thanks. I was able to apply this logic for my huge dataset and it does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution that I wanted to put on the first version of this question, in case you don't want to use Pandas:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

data = """
    XYZ
    XYZ
    ABC
    ABC
    MNP
    MNP
    Fruit
    Apple
    price
    30
    Number
    10
    Fruit
    kiwi
    Number
    20
    Fruit
    grape
    price
    12"""

def doit(data):

    table = []

    data = re.split(r'\s+', data)
    currentFruit = None
    while len(data):
        line = data.pop(0)
        if line == "Fruit":
            if currentFruit:
                table.append(currentFruit)
            currentFruit = { 'name': data.pop(0) }
        elif currentFruit:
            currentFruit[line] = data.pop(0)
    table.append(currentFruit)

    print "%-9s%-9s%-9s" % ("Fruit", "price", "Number")
    for fruit in table:
        print "%-9s%-9s%-9s" % (fruit['name'],
                                fruit['price'] if 'price' in fruit else '',
                                fruit['Number'] if 'Number' in fruit else '')

doit(data)
```